# get request using a script python and web API in sonarQUbe

Tags: python, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'v recently started using sonar.cloud.whatever.com. on the profolio I have by default the analysisi result for a master branch by default for any given project so if I need to collect the information for multiple branched in this project I have to select those branched one by one.
For the moment I don't know if there is any other simple way to do this without given by sonar
so I stated a script on python using the webservice API given by sonar .
I stated (just to try the result) by collecting all the issues using /api/issues/search

```
import json
import sys
import os
import requests
def usage():

    print("hello")
 
def collectIssues():
    r=requests.get('https://sonar.cloud.sec.NotToMention.com/api/issues/search? componentKeys=project_key&statuses=OPEN')
    print("le code ",r.status_code)
    print(r.url)
    #print(r.headers)
    if(r.status_code!=200):
        exit(0)
    
    data=r.json() 
    print(r.headers,"\n\n")
    print(data)
    print(data['issues'])  
 
def main(args):
 
    collectIssues()
 
if __name__== '__main__':
 
    main(sys.argv)
    exit(0)
```

if I copy the link and browse it I have the right result with total 1000 issues, but the result of this script gives total 0 and issues = [].

(I want just to sign that project_name and NotToMention are not the real values I replaced them here for security issues.)

the result of this script is :

status_code :  200

https://sonar.cloud.NotTOMention.com/api/issues/search?componentKeys=project_name&statuses=OPEN

JSON RESULT :

{'total': 0, 'p': 1, 'ps': 100, 'paging': {'pageIndex': 1, 'pageSize': 100, 'total': 0}, 'effortTotal': 0, 'debtTotal': 0, 'issues': [], 'components': [], 'facets': []}

thanks for any advice.

best regards

Comment: Can you post the actual server response you get?

Comment: are you sure that if you hit the url in the browser you are getting the correct result? can you try the same in different browser or incognito, because it could be a possibility that some extra info is being passed in your get call from browser whereas your script call doesn't have that.

Comment: also, instead of running your script. try the code in python interpretor or IDLE

import requests, do a get and check the response.

Comment: I tried incognito mode, I have no result and I tried with other browser without login to sonarQube, I had no result ( I had the same as when I run the script ) but when I'm login I have the right response. I don't know how this works but do you think that  I need a something such a token in my script, ( but this script is supposed to be used by others( not just me ) )